# Array push in array in js to a variable from php

Tags: javascript, arrays, array-push

I was wondering how can I use array push to add values for `DeliveryArea`. All values will come from php variables. I am beginner in using JS and want to learn and invade js.

```
var Category = {
    "Status": ["Unpaid", "Paid", "Pending"],
    "OrderDate": ["123", "123", "123"],
    "DeliveryArea": [],
}
```

Comment: You can access the `DeliveryArea` array using the dot notation and use `array#push` method to add new value to it.

Comment: Use `Category.DeliveryArea.push("value")`

Answer (score 1):

Use object name along with key name like this `Category.DeliveryArea`

```js
var Category = {

  "Status": ["Unpaid", "Paid", "Pending"],
  "OrderDate": ["123", "123", "123"],
  "DeliveryArea": [],
}

let arr = ['arr1', 'arr2', 'arr3'];

arr.forEach(function(item) {
  Category.DeliveryArea.push(item)

})

console.log(Category)
```

Use square bracket if you wish to access the key through a variable

```js
var Category = {
  "Status": ["Unpaid", "Paid", "Pending"],
  "OrderDate": ["123", "123", "123"],
  "DeliveryArea": [],
}

let keyName = 'DeliveryArea'

let arr = ['arr1', 'arr2', 'arr3'];

arr.forEach(function(item) {
  Category[keyName].push(item)

})

console.log(Category)
```